# How to add an external sound file when deploying a project in visual studio?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, installation

i have a program that plays a sound when a button is clicked , 
 in deployment , how to put the file to be included with the setup.msi or setup.exe also , 
 how to set the path in which it will be put ?

Answer (score 1):

The recommended approach is to store it in [Binary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa367825%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) table. A custom action can [extract it](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa368250%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) when installation starts and another one can delete it when installation ends.